# Export query to new Excel workbook using Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to write contents of the Access query to newly opened Excel workbook.

The code is opening the new Excel workbook with empty sheets, not writing the query to sheet.

```vb
Dim myExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet
    
Set myExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")   
   
Set myBook = myExcel.Workbooks.Add(1)
Set mySheet = myBook.Worksheets(1) 
    
myExcel.Visible = True   
    
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, qrytbl1, mySheet, True   
    
Set myBook = Nothing
Set mySheet = Nothing
Set myExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: not throwing any errors

Comment: Its just  `select tbl1.name,tbl1.id,tbl1.ecid FROM tbl1;`

Comment: It is query table in access db

Comment: But why i'm not getting any error. Is any other way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the export to spreadsheet function, however keep in mind this writes to a new file. Not sure if this would work with the file already open. Another approach is using the CopyFromRecordset method after creating the recordset.

Here is an example.

```
Public Sub DisplayRecordset()
    Dim myrs As DAO.Recordset ' Create a recordset to hold the data
    Dim myExcel As New Excel.Application ' Create Excel with Early binding
    Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet
    
    Set mySheet = myExcel.Workbooks.Add(1).Worksheets(1) ' Create Workbook
    Set myrs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select tbl1.name,tbl1.id,tbl1.ecid FROM tbl1;") ' Define recordset
    
    'Add header names
    For i = 0 To myrs.Fields.Count - 1
        mySheet.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = myrs.Fields(i).Name
    Next
    
    'Add data to excel and make Excel visible
    mySheet.Range("**A2**").CopyFromRecordset myrs
    myExcel.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: for me the second to last row isn't working... I have used :
mySheet.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset myrs